# SQLite CREATE TRIGGER: What is the default if neither BEFORE nor AFTER has been specified?

Tags: triggers, sqlite

From [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) documentation for `CREATE TRIGGER`, one can see that `BEFORE`, `AFTER` or `INSTEAD OF` may be ommited.

So, when is trigger fired when none is specified? Where is it documented?

[image: CREATE TRIGGER]

Comment: +1 Thanks! I was going to ask the same question, but noticed yours. (I changed the title to be a little bit clearer, that's the title I was going to use for my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlite> create table t(x, triggervalue);
sqlite> insert into t(x) values(1);
sqlite> create trigger tt
   ...> update of x on t
   ...> begin
   ...>   update t set triggervalue = x;
   ...> end;
sqlite> update t set x = 2;
sqlite> select triggervalue from t;
1
```

So the default happens to be BEFORE.

This is not documented anywhere, and the syntax without BEFORE/AFTER looks so ugly that I guess nobody thinks of using it.